# Задать размер вектора, который служит значением в словаре

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Одним из членов в моем классе является такой словарь

```
map<int, vector<string>>
```

Возможно ли указать размер вектора по умолчанию?

Comment: Нет, если только не написать свою замену/обертку/унаследоваться от вектора.

Comment: По умолчанию *для чего*? В тип вектора количество элементов не входит, так что задание в параметре типа - бессмысленно. В конструкторе `map` - тоже, так как в него значение не передается... По сути единственное место, где можно использовать некоторое умолчание - при обращении для чтения к некоторому отсутствующему элементу отображения...

Comment: @Harry чтобы когда в словарь добавлялся новый элемент, вектор сразу имел бы несколько пустых строк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать по умолчанию нельзя, т.к. вектор будет создаваться при добавлении элемента в словарь. Можно только использовать фиксированный `std::array` вместо вектора.

P.S. Если ключи словаря числовые то будет лучше его заменить на тот же вектор.